# Best way to use Perl's DBI to UPDATE a row, and print the response to the cmd-line?

Tags: perl, dbi

Have some Perl code which is using the DBI module - (the code is at work, I can post it in the morning if needed) - but mainly trying to get a sense of what DBI needs to do an update to a row -- and get either errors back, or confirmation that the UPDATE was executed.

(Below is just a basic example, feel free to give your own example and sample DDL if you want... just want some code that I know works. I've run my code via the Perl PtkDB debugger, and can "see" the SQL it generating and executing -- even paste in in the MySQL consol and execute it... but it's doing nothing in the Perl, even thought the select statements are working. Mainly just want a better idea of how DBI is handling UPDATE to MySQL, and if there's any built in feature in DBI that would make debugging this more simple. Thanks!)

So, please supply one full Perl script that:

- Sets the connection (MySQL)
- SELECT row two based on ID and get the first and last name
- Lowercase the names
- UPDATE the table
- disconnect

**Sample TABLE**

```
<COL01>Id <COL02>FirstName <COL03>LastName
<ROW01-COL01>1 <ROW01-COL02>John <ROW01-COL03>Smith
<ROW02-COL01>2 <ROW02-COL02>Jane <ROW02-COL03>Doe
```

---

**UPDATE (1):** Code in question is below. The ONLY thing I've changed is remove code not related to the issue and the config info (eg database name, user, password, etc.) and made the value production for the variables super simple. This code was created by someone else and in a legacy code base.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

sub dbOpen {
    my $dsn; 
    my $dbh;
    $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=databasename;host=localhost;port=3306";
    $dbh = DBI->connect( $dsn, "root", "password" ) ||
    print STDERR "FATAL: Could not connect to database.\n$DBI::errstr\n";
    $dbh->{ AutoCommit } = 0;
    return($dbh);
} # END sub dbOpen

my $Data;
$Data = &dbOpen();

my ($sql,$rs,$sql_update_result);
my $column2,
my $column3;
my $id;
$column2 = 2,
$column3 = 3;
$id = 1;

$sql = "UPDATE table SET column1 = NULL, column2 = ".$column2.", column3 = ".$column3." WHERE id = ".$id.";";
$rs = $Data->prepare( $sql );
$rs->execute() || &die_clean("Couldn't execute\n$sql\n".$Data->errstr."\n" );
($sql_update_result) = $rs->fetchrow;

$Data->disconnect();
```

DDL for MySQL -- if needed, just comment and I'll post one.

---

UPDATE (2):

Final found one complete example, though it's only for a select statement and not even inserting any VARs into the SQL: http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#Simple_Examples

Comment: Read the DBI documentation paying particular attention to these methods: `DBI->connect`, `$dbh->disconnect`, `$dbh->do`, `$sth->prepare`, and `$sth->execute`. Those a bit of SQL knowledge are all you need.

Comment: @downvote: Wow, -1 for what, guess it's easy to read 34,241 words present on the http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm page, right?

Comment: You don't need to read all 34,241 words to learn how to issue an SQL update. Asking others to write complete code for you when you haven't even showed that you tried anything doesn't engender a lot of positive vibes.

Comment: @friedo: Did you read my post, or just the question? So far no one has answered the core of my question. What is the real issue that's stated in the post? It's that the SQL generated by DBI works, but only if I cut and paste it out of the debugger to MySQL cmd. Sure, question could be better. Would this be more clear, how do I print the command given to MySQL and MySQL's response and response time? Cheers, and thanks for your time!

Comment: +1 @reinierpost: Meaning that the SQL statement given to DBI to execute works after the variables have been inserted by Perl. In the debugger, I can take that SQL statement and execute in by hand without editing and it works. DBI gives no error, and I'm unable to figure out how to see for sure the command sent, or the response given by the database back to DBI. Make sense, or no? Thanks!

Comment: @blunders: However it still isn't clear to me what you really want to ask.  What is the problem you're experiencing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost copy and paste from [`DBI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI) Synopsis:

```
use DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $auth, \%attr);
$statement = "UPDATE some_table SET som_col = ? WHERE id = ?";
$rv  = $dbh->do($statement, undef, $som_val, $id); 
$DBI::err && die $DBI::errstr;
$rc  = $dbh->disconnect;
```

Comment: +1 @wk: Great, thanks -- your synopsis of the Synopsis makes way more sense to me, since I'd looked at it and the powerpoint briefly too. Main thing I'm still missing is how to get a position report back that it was a success. Appears there's a way to do this, but can't figure it out. For explain, I did find code that would let you get back how long it took the SQL to run via the DBI itself; or at least it appeared that way. Again, thanks!

Comment: `do` returns the number of rows affected or `undef` on error . If there was an error, `DBI::err` will contain the native database engine error code. `DBI::errstr` will hold the error message.

Comment: +1 @Paco Regodón: New to Perl, how do I print the command given to MySQL and MySQL's response and response time? I believe what I've been looking at in the debugger is the $rv variable, which if I'm correctly recalling produce the SQL statement I was able to cut-n-paste into MySQL's cmdline, execute, and have the update work. Is there a way to print the "do" to see the results, if it was $do I'd know the answer, but in this case I have no idea how to reference it in a print statement. Also, feel free to post this as an answer - since this is really the core of my question/issue. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand you very well. Can you edit your question and add some code?

Comment: @Paco Regodón: Thanks, sure I'll post code in 2-hours, at home now -- that said, my concern is with the "correct" way to do the update. DBI been around 10+ years, and some of the code cut-n-paste around the net is likely old - meaning I'm looking for someone that really knows the current best practices in DBI. Also, as for my question -- I'll attempt to restate it. I want to print to the system commandline what is being sent to the database (not what's being stored to be sent, though if that's the only way - that will have to do) -- see next comment... (again, thanks!)

Comment: @Paco Regodón: Also, aside from getting the command being sent to the database via a print statement -- I'd like to be able to print the results/response from the database back to the code. Request to get the response time to execute the code is more important, but not as important as seeing the command sent, and the response of the results of that command from the database. Again, thank you +1 for the reply and request for clarification.

Comment: @Paco Regodón: Posted the code as an update for the description of the question.

Comment: @wk: So, your code does not work -- at the very least it's missing "dbi:driver:" - or at least that's the first error Perl through when it's run.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use `do` when updating or deleting since these operations doesn't return any row.
So, in order to have a little debug, i would modify your code like this:

```
my $sql = "UPDATE table SET column1=NULL, column2=$column2, column3=$column3 WHERE id=$id";
print STDERR "SQL: $sql\n"

my $numrows = $Data->do($sql);

if (not defined $numrows) {
   print STDERR "ERROR: $DBI::errstr";
} else {
   print STDERR "INFO: $numrows rows updated";
}
```

You can measure query response times from within your perl code, but since it is a database thing, i recommend you using any Mysql specialized tool (i don't use MySQL, sorry).

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered something a bit higher level - like [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/)?

Comment: +1 @davorg: Thanks Dave, I have looked at the ORM DBIx::Class -- though want to understand how DBI is working first. Guess I should look in your book, (which I just did, the book being "Data Munging with Perl" ) -- there's a lot of info in there about the DBI functions. Beyond the docs for DBIx::Class -- do you have any additional suggestions on learning it? Cheers!

Comment: That book is ten years old. A lot of things have changed in that time. DBIx::Class didn't exist ten years ago. If I was writing the book now I would definitely cover DBIx::Class in preference to DBI. The docs for DBIx::Class are great I'd particularly recommend the DBIx::Class::Manual pages that are indexed at http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual.pod

Comment: +1 @davorg: Thanks found the example to be of the most use (which I'd missed before) http://search.cpan.org/~abraxxa/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Example.pod

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to return the values, lowercase them in Perl, then update the rows. Just do that in one SQL statement:

```
my $sql = "UPDATE table SET column2=lower(column2) WHERE id = ?";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
foreach my $id (@ids) {
    $sth->execute($id);
}
```

You also want to use placeholders to prevent [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) from visiting.